# Leaflet bindpop() using lazyload of images

Tags: javascript, leaflet, lazy-loading, marker

I'm using leaflet to put some markers on a map. I have set that, clicking on a marker, a popup will be opened showing an image. Here's a brief example:

```
var map = L.map('map')
   .addLayer(tile)
   .setView([initLat, initLon], initZoom);

var m = L.marker([lat, lon])
   .bindPopup('<img src="1.jpg"/>')
   .addTo(map);
```

My objective is to load those images ("1.jpg" in the example above) using lazy load, so it's only loaded when I click on the marker.

Does anyone knows how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set the content of the popup when the popup is opened.

Let's create a custom popup with a `lazyload` option and without content :

```
var m = L.marker([0, 0])
    .bindPopup(L.popup({
        lazyload: '<img src="1.jpg"/>'
    }))
    .addTo(map);
```

You can then set a global handler to fill your popup when needed:

```
map.on('popupopen', function(e) {
    var popen = e.popup;
    if (popen.options.lazyload) {
        popen.setContent(popen.options.lazyload);
    }
});
```

And a demo:

```js
var map = L.map('map', {
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 1
});

var m = L.marker([-30, 0])
    .bindPopup(L.popup({
        lazyload: '<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/shfxy.jpg?s=32&g=1" />'
    }))
    .addTo(map);

map.on('popupopen', function(e) {
    var popen = e.popup;
    if (popen.options.lazyload) {
        popen.setContent(popen.options.lazyload);
    }
});
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.3.1/leaflet.css"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.3.1/leaflet.js"></script>

<div id='map'></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, nikoshr! So, how I could check if it works as we expect?

Comment: Open you browser tools / network tab and check if the image is loaded when you open the popup

Comment: I'm very very grateful to you, nikoshr! You don't know what does it means to me! A lot of bandwidth saved! :) Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Actually in the case where you fill your popup with a String content (like you did with `.bindPopup('<img src="1.jpg"/>')`, Leaflet converts it (through `innerHTML`) to DOM nodes only when the Popup is first opened on a map. Therefore your image will be loaded only at that moment, which is exactly the lazy loading behaviour you are looking for.

So you do not need to do anything extra from what you already have done in your question code:

(make sure you refresh your page / clear your cache to see the image loading pass in the browser network requests)

```js
var map = L.map('map', {
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 1
});

var m = L.marker([-30, 0])
    .bindPopup('<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/shfxy.jpg?s=32&g=1" />')
    .addTo(map);
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.3.1/leaflet.css"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.3.1/leaflet.js"></script>

<div id='map'></div>
```

Comment: Not really. If I have 20 markups and I do nothing, there will be 20 pictures loaded, even if I haven't clicked over anyone.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Please can you share an example where the behaviour you describe can be seen? The code snippet in the above answer proves otherwise, but you may have set your code differently.